# Does Facebook have public API's for searching Marketplace listings?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to create a project that requires searching Facebook marketplace listings but in my preliminary research it seems this is no longer an option. Is this true? If so, are there any workarounds?

I prompted chat gpt which shared outdated information of using the GET request below. The endpoint no longer exists and I couldn't find anything that accomplishes the same task in facebook's developer documents.

my GET request url: `https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/search?q=<SEARCH_QUERY>&type=post&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Comment: "I asked chat gpt"—ChatGPT is _not intelligent_.

Comment: Agreed. Just sharing a bit of what I tried/researched already.